# Main module not found

Tags: python

When I run the following command line:python3 /Users/Ron/AppData/Local/Packages/transcribe.py
or python3 -m /Users/Ron/AppData/Local/Packages/transcribe.py, I get an error stating "can't find the '**main**' module ".Here below is my file.py

```
#!/usr/bin/venv python

from pathlib import PureWindowsPath 
path = PureWindowsPath('/Users/Ron/AppData/Local/Packages/transcribe.py').is_absolute() 


def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
gcs_uri = 'gs://appliedlinguistics66/speech/Why Jony Ive is Leaving Apple.mp4

from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types
     client = speech.SpeechClient()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

with open((path, 'rb') as audio_file:
content = audio_file.read()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    model=video
    audio_channel_count= 1,
    enable_separate_recognition_per_channel= false,
   maxAlternatives= 1,
   profanity_filter= False
   enable_word_time_offsets= True,
   enable_automatic_punctuation= True,
   metadata.object.RecognitionMetadata
    language_code='en-US')
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
  response = operation.result(timeout=90)

for result in response.results:
    print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
    print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))

    main()
```

Comment: The declaration of `gcs_uri` lacks a closing `'`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you make a question try to give a minimum information. What did you try? SO is not a free coding/debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have

def main():
    code

anywhere. So put all your code inside the def main() definition then you can invoke it as you have done. For example:

```
def main():
    print("I am in main!")

main()
```

> > "I am in main!"